# Return to previous spot in loop after try catch?

Tags: java

```
        } else if (selectionKey == 2) {
            System.out.println("Please enter the item name");
            if (s.nextLine() != "") {
                item = s.nextLine();
            }
            try {
            ZybezChecker zb = new ZybezChecker(item);
            zb.getAveragePrice();
            System.out.println(zb.toString());
            } catch(Exception e) {
                System.out.println("Something went wrong. Perhaps an invalid item name?");
            }
```

That's my code atm. How do I return back to the if statement and continue the loop after it catches?

Comment: If you need to do things like this you have a design flaw. Try moving code to a function or something.

Answer (score 0):

You could embed it in a loop like,

```
for (;;) { // <-- start an infinite loop
    System.out.println("Please enter the item name");
    if (s.nextLine() != "") {
        item = s.nextLine();
    }
    try {
        ZybezChecker zb = new ZybezChecker(item);
        zb.getAveragePrice();
        System.out.println(zb.toString());
        break; // <-- terminate the infinite loop.
    } catch(Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Something went wrong. Perhaps an "
            + "invalid item name?");
        e.printStackTrace(); // <-- tell them what went wrong.
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think (if I understand your question and code correctly) that what you want is a loop containing the s.nextLine(). Note that I am assuming several things here:

- s is a Scanner or something equivalent that reads input from the user
- an exception is thrown if the user enters invalid input
- you want to keep asking the user for input until they enter something valid

If this is the case, then you should create a loop like this:

```
while (true) {
    System.out.println("Please enter the item name");
    if (s.nextLine() != "") {
        item = s.nextLine();
    } 

    try {
        ZybezChecker zb = new ZybezChecker(item);
        zb.getAveragePrice();
        System.out.println(zb.toString());
        break;
    } catch(Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Something went wrong. Perhaps an invalid item name?");
    }
}
```

Also, why are you calling nextLine() twice? When you call it the first time, it will read a line from the scanner. When you call it again, it will not return the same line; it will instead wait for a new line. This means the user has to enter some random string, then enter the actual value. Finally, you should NEVER use == or != on Strings. Since they are reference types, you are essentially checking if they occupy the same location in memory, rather than if they are equal. Use s.nextLine().equals("") instead.